# Content flash when selecting an item in an isotope container

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a small demo/prototype app and am using isotope to animate filtering for a group of divs. The divs are colored blocks with some text inside them that updates automatically using an .ajax function to get JSON data.

The app is a set of ASP.NET MVC full views and a few partial views. The tiles sit in one view. Clicking a tile takes the user to a new view page for the 'content' of that tile. There is an animated fade-out/fade-in between views. (The dev that made this originally had partial views, but a requirement for the back button to work was added. This is why all the content was changed to full views...and unfortunately why the transitions are choppier.)

My problem is that on a tile click, the isotope div flashes before fading out.

Here's a little diagram in the interest of clarity. :)

[image: Isotope fadeout flash]

There's nothing in the jQuery click event handling the fades that would cause this kind of flash. The click event fades out the current innerContent and reloads the next view with window.location.href after the content is faded out. The main MVC layout handles fading in for the next view. When I step through or when I do some alertbox debugging (insert alert("i'm at this point") at each point of the click function) I don't get a flash.

This is the function handling the tile click:

```
var theTileId = $("#" + divId).attr("data-tile-id");
```

var appName = "Applications > " + $("#" + divId).attr("data-tile-appName");
localStorage.setItem("breadcrumb", appName);

$("#innercontainer").fadeOut(250, function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Application360", "Larry")?an=' + appName;
});

And this is the main layout function handing the fade-in for all views:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#innercontainer").animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0, function () {
            $("#innercontainer").delay(400).animate({ opacity: '1' }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'swing' });
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on what may be happening? I apologize for not posting a jsfiddle, but the app is a little big and considered sensitive (you know, the usual). I can try to whip up something later if it's really necessary. It's not super-critical this be solved for the prototype but it would be nice to make it look as smooth as I can. Thanks!

Comment: No I never did. Had several devs look at it and nobody had any suggestions. More typical 'web development' unfortunately. :( The only suggestion I had was that we were refreshing the entire page, so even though the reload was happening when everything was faded it, it was flashing. Using partial views we didn't have that problem but had to change away from that for some reason, don't remember now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and my solution was to force it to use jquery.  Isotope gives 3 options for the animationEngine: 'best-available', 'css' and 'jquery'.  Then set your animationOptions.  See [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#animationengine) for more detail.

note: any additional .animate() may cause flashes with the 'jquery' option set as it will run the animation twice.